# Error running Visual Studio Code

Tags: 22.04, snap, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run VScode 1.79.2 in Ubuntu 22.04.2 but it doesn't work. Using `code --verbose` it shows the error message: `libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so) (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)`

After trying different possible solutions for this problem I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68231387/starting-vs-code-hangs-with-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-can-i-point-to-a-libstdc which seems to be similar to my problem but with a different version of GLIBCXX.

I ran this command and it is true that this version is missing:

```
$ strings /snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

However, if I look for this in `/usr/lib` the required version is there:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
...
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_3.4.29
GLIBCXX_3.4.30
GLIBCXX_3.4.31
GLIBCXX_3.4.32
GLIBCXX_TUNABLES
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I tried to remove the libstdc++.so.6 file in `/snap/core20` and recreate it pointing to the file in `/usr/lib`, but I cannot remove this file in spite of having all the permissions: `rm: cannot remove '/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6': Read-only file system`

Any possible solution to this problem? Thanks